# Is there any free tool for generating POCO, mappings and context from existing db structure?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm started using EF5 Code First on my project and i want to create bounded contexts to prevent complexity of my system. I wonder, Is there any free tool for generating POCO, mappings and context from existing db structure?

Comment: Hibernate does it for Java; perhaps NHibernate can do the same for .NET.

Comment: Yes, NHibernate tools can do it but i'm using EF as ORM.

Comment: Better ask Microsoft, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)